# json_decode on retrieved json string from mysql does not work

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a string json that gives the following var dump:

```
"[[{"TransactionID":"00416","OrderID":"000926","TransactionOrderItemID":"001123","LastUpdate":"2009-10-28 13:03:31","CustomerID":"184","Company_name":"Test123","Invoiced":"0","SubItemsCount":"2","ProductID":"1","ProductTypesID":"1","ProductTypeName":"Phone","ProductName":"Phone Line (Home)","IncludePST":"1","BillType":"Monthly","BillingCycle":"Monthly","Status":"Active","CreationDate":"2009-10-28","ActivationStartDate":"2009-10-28","NextNotificationDate":"2009-10-27","OverWritePrice":"-1","PriceEconomic":"26.00","BasePrice":"26.0000","ProRate":"Yes","InvoicePrice":"3.35","ServicePeriod":" Pro-Rate: Oct-28-2009 - Oct-31-2009","EndDate":"2009-10-31"}]]"
```

When I try to decode as:

```
json_decode( $json, true);
```

The result is just null.  $json is from db.
Note that I am only showing a subset of full data.
The questions is, this is variable from db.  If double quote is the problem, how to cast it?

Comment: I would suggest the problem lies in the part you omitted

Comment: Fair suggestion.  But when I get this var dump, and put into a string, it decodes as expected.

Comment: That string decodes fine, so I agree with Greg.  The problem is in the part that you did not post here.

Comment: how is the string getting stored into $json?
I tried it with that string wrapped in single quote instead of double and json_decode() worked fine.

Comment: You are right Jim.  If it is wrapped in single quote it works fine.  But the trouble is how to do this automatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can call `json_last_error()` to get more info about what went wrong.

For example this way:

```
json_decode($string);

switch(json_last_error())
{
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        echo ' - No errors';
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be a problem with UTF-8 characters.  Many posts on the json_decode manual page [suggest that some conversion issues](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#86997) need to be handled.

Try using `json_decode(utf8_encode($json));`

Comment: How do you know string is in ISO-8859-1 encoding?